# Different between two statements

Tags: perl

What is the difference between these two piece of code?

```
my $a = ();

print $a;
```

```
print ();
```

Comment: Note: Don't ever use `$a` and `$b` in code in Perl, or it'll probably bite you at some point. These are special variables, used by `sort`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scalar assignment operator evaluates its operands in scalar context. The stub operator (`()`) evaluates to `undef` in scalar context, so

```
my $a = ();       # Create $a initialized to undef, then assign undef to $a.
```

is the same as

```
my $a = undef;    # Create $a initialized to undef, then assign undef to $a.
```

which simplifies to

```
my $a;            # Create $a initialized to undef.
```

---

The `print` operator evaluates its operands in list context. The stub operator (`()`) evaluates to an empty list in list context, so

```
print( () );      # Print no scalars, so print nothing.
```

is quite different than

```
print( $a );      # Print one scalar whose value is undef.
```

and

```
print( undef );   # Print one scalar whose value is undef.
```

---

But you didn't use

```
print( () );
```

You actually used

```
print ();
```

which is a weird way of writing

```
print();
```

When you don't specify any arguments, `print` prints `$_`, so

```
print ();         # Print one scalar ($_) whose value is quite possibly undef.
```

is equivalent to

```
print($_);        # Print one scalar ($_) whose value is quite possibly undef.
```

If warnings had been on, you would have received the following warning:

```
print (...) interpreted as function
```

Comment: @Miller pointed out an error in my answer. It has been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

In the first line you assign the content of the (empty) list to the scalar `$a`, therefore `$a` will be set to`undef`.

In the second case you're printing an empty (but valid) list.

HINT: add `use warnings` at the top of the file, and you'll see a runtime warning from trying to print out an undefined variable.

Comment: No list is assigned to `$a`. `()` is not a list literal (aka comma operator) as observed by the lack of `,`, and it doesn't return a list in scalar context (nothing does cause it would crash `perl`). `perlop` doesn't mention `()`, so I use the name returned by `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'my $a = ();'`: "stub".

Comment: The second statement is not printing an empty list, but is actually a bare functional call.  It will therefore print `$_`.